# Question About Proof for Covering Space and Compactness

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, covering-spaces

We are asked to prove the following:

> Let $q: E \to X$ be a covering map with $q^{-1}(x)$ finite.  Show that $E$ is compact if and only if $X$ is compact.

The forward direction is trivial, and for the reverse direction, my professor gave this proof:

> Let $\{\tilde{U}_\alpha\}$ be a cover of $E$.  By assumption, for any $x \in X$, the fiber $q^{-1}(x)$ is finite. So, $q^{-1}(x)$ can be contained in a finite number of sets in $\{\tilde{U}_\alpha\}$.  Denote these sets by $\{\tilde{U}_1, \ldots, \tilde{U}_b\}$, and let $\tilde{U}_x := \bigcup_{j=1}^b \tilde{U}_j$.  Since $q$ is a covering map, there exists a neighborhood of $x$, $V_x$, such that $V_x$ is evenly covered by $q$.  Without loss of generality, assume $q^{-1}(V_x) \subset \tilde{U}_x$.  Now, $\{V_x\}_{x \in X}$ is a cover for $X$, so there is a finite subcover, $\{V_{x_1}, V_{x_2}, \ldots, V_{x_n}\}$.  It follows that $E = q^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{x_i}) = \bigcup q^{-1}(V_{x_i}) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \tilde{U}_{x_i}$, so we have a finite subcover.

I understand the proof, except for the sentence,

> Without loss of generality, assume $q^{-1}(V_x) \subset \tilde{U}_x$.

I don't understand why we can do this; she said something about taking a smaller open subset, but I wasn't sure how we could do this and still guarantee an evenly covered neighborhood.

I've seen an alternative proof of this before, but it was much more involved, so if anyone could help me understand this part, that would be great.

Comment: If you have one homeomorphism already, restricting to an open subset is still a homeo onto its image.

Comment: So this means every evenly covered neighborhood as an evenly covered, open subset?

Comment: Yes.  Check the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but a bit short. Here is a more precise argument.

Write $q^{-1}(x) = \{e_1,\ldots,e_b\}$. Pick $\tilde U_j$ from the given open cover of $E$ such that $e_j \in \tilde U_j$. Then clearly $q^{-1}(x) \subset \tilde{U}_x := \bigcup_{j=1}^b \tilde{U}_j$.

Since $V_x$ is evenly covered, we have $q^{-1}(V_x) = \bigcup_{j=1}^b V_j$ with open $V_j \subset E$ which are mapped by $q$ homeomorphically onto $V_x$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $e_j \in V_j$ (otherwise reindex). Then $W_j = \tilde{U}_j \cap V_j$ is an open neigborhood of $e_j$. Now define
$$V'_x = \bigcap_{j=1}^b q(W_j) \subset V_x .$$
This is an open neigborhood of $x$ which has the property
$$q^{-1}(V'_x) \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^b W_j \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^b \tilde{U}_j = \tilde{U}_x .$$